# Sie und ich freuen sich/uns

Tags: grammatical-number, reflexive, subject

Vor einigen Tagen bin ich auf etwas gestoßen, das ich nicht verstehe.

Warum sagt man:

> 1) Meine Frau und ich freuen **sich** über deinen Besuch

und nicht

> 2) Meine Frau und ich freuen **uns** über deinen Besuch,

wenn das Subjekt »meine Frau und ich« eindeutig eine erste Person Plural ist? Ist der zweite Satz auch korrekt und geläufig?

Eine Erklärung dazu habe ich in keiner Grammatik gefunden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Von den beiden Sätzen ist nur der zweite richtig. Der erste ist standardsprachlich falsch, aber regional umgangssprachlich in Verwendung. (Details weiter unten)

---

Das Subjekt des nachgefragten Satzes ist eine Aufzählung mit zwei Bestandteilen, und daher müssen das Verb und auch das drauf verweisende Reflexivpronomen im Plural stehen. Ich erwähne das, weil auch die Wahl von Singular oder Plural bei solchen Sätzen manchem Probleme macht.

Das war aber der einfache Teil. Schwierig wird es jetzt:

Von den beiden Bestandteilen der Aufzählung steht einer in der dritten Person (meine Frau) und der anderen in der ersten Person (ich), und das macht die Sache ein wenig knifflig. Für das Verb ist das egal, weil die Flexion von Verben im Plural für die erste Person und für die dritte Person gleich sind. Um den Schwierigkeitsgrad  zu erhöhen, wähle ich daher anderes Beispiel:

> Du und er {Form von *irren*} {Reflexivpronomen}.

<sup>*Ich habe statt »freuen« das Verb »irren« gewählt, weil es selten passiert, dass ein Außenstehender behauptet, dass sich zwei Leute freuen. Beim Irren kommt diese Behauptung aber im Gegensatz dazu fast immer von einem Außenstehenden. Grammatisch funktionieren aber beide Verben gleich.*</sup>

Jetzt ist zunächst auch die Form des Verbs unklar, weil hier zweite und dritte Person zu kombinieren sind, und das jetzt auch für das Verb unterschiedliche Formen ergibt.

**Lösung**

Die Lösung des Problems ist eigentlich recht einfach: Man ersetzt das ganze Subjekt in Gedanken durch ein Personalpronomen, welches das ganze Subjekt repräsentiert, und wählt dann Verb und Reflexivpronomen so, dass sie dazu passen:

> *richtig:* Du und er irrt euch. (*Ihr* irrt euch.)
>   *falsch:* <s>Du und er irren sich.</s>

Und daher auch:

> *richtig:* Meine Frau und ich freuen uns ... (*Wir* freuen uns ...)
>   *falsch:* <s>Meine Frau und ich freuen sich.</s>

Obwohl diese Sätze so, wie sie da stehen, völlig korrekt sind, kann man etwas mehr sprachliches Wohlgefühl herstellen, indem man das zusammenfassende Personalpronomen in den Satz einbindet:

> Du und er, ihr irrt euch.
>   Meine Frau und ich, wir freuen uns ...

Das nennt man eine Herausstellung des Subjekts nach links.

---

**umgangssprachlich**

Zumindest in der Metropolregion Wien ist dennoch das Pronomen *»sich«* neben dem eigentlich richtigen *»uns«* geläufig, sogar dann, wenn explizit *»wir«* gesagt wird:

> Treffen wir *sich* später noch auf einen Kaffee?
>   Sie kommen mir so bekannt vor. Kann es sein, was wir *sich* kennen?

Allerdings hört man in solchen Fällen *»uns«* dennoch weitaus häufiger, aber eben nicht ausschließlich.

Ob das auch in anderen Regionen so der Fall sit, entzieht sich meiner Kenntnis.

Comment: Zum letzten Absatz: Ich habe das noch nie gehört (Süddeutschland) und finde es grausig :)

Answer (score 8):

1) ist falsch, nur 2) ist richtig.

Der Gebrauch des Reflexivpronomens »sich« wäre allerdings richtig, wenn es dem Subjekt vorausginge:

> Es freuen sich meine Frau und ich über deinen Besuch.

Das so zu sagen ist aber nicht üblich.

Quelle: [Duden - Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle (Ausgabe 2016)](https://books.google.de/books?id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&vq=Subjektteile%20mit%20kopulativen%20Konjunktionen&hl=de#v=onepage&q=Wenn%20das%20Reflexivpronomen%20dem%20Subjekt%20vorausgeht%20und%20im%20ersten%20Subjektteil&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

"Sich" geht mit dem Infinitiv. "Sich freuen."

"Uns" geht mit "Sie und ich" (wir). "Wir freuen uns."